# How to add comments to each forum post in yii, using bbii forum module and comments-module

Tags: php, yii, module, yii-extensions, comments

I am using Yii [bbii forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bbii/) module and it works fine. But now I want to add [comments-module](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/comments-module/) so every forum post could be seperately commented.

At the begining it might look:
[image]

I followed instruction what is [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/comments-module/), but I can't make it work :(

[image] 
[image]

And why I even need to include this file, if I want to add just comment?

[image]

When I added the same widget to user page (just for testing) - I got "This item cann't be commentable" and it's fine because probably I don't have correct configuration in main.php.
[image]

Difference between widget in user model view and forum view is data passed in it.
Here:

```
   public function actionPostComment()
        {
            if(isset($_POST['Comment']) && Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            {
                $comment = new Comment();
                $comment->attributes = $_POST['Comment'];
                var_dump($comment);
```

var_dump returned [this](http://mikimauss.lv/comment.txt) when tried to submit comment in forum, and [here](http://mikimauss.lv/user.txt) in user view page.

And probably it is not even possible to combine these to modules? I'm really new in Yii.

**Updated:**

Basically what I have done is:

- exstracted comment module (under protected->modules)
- in main.php (under protected->config) added all cofiguration in modules array:
- ```
   'comments'=>array(                
              //you may override default config for all connecting models
              'defaultModelConfig' => array(
                  //only registered users can post comments
                  'registeredOnly' => false,
                  'useCaptcha' => false,
                   .......
  ```
- and in view file *_post.php* added following:

  ```
         <?php $this->widget('comments.widgets.ECommentsListWidget', array(
                                          'model' => $data,
                                      ));
  ```
- and `var_dump($data)` gives [this](http://mikimauss.lv/comment.txt) (when this is called in controller where post is reseaved).

Comment: Your question contains a lot of information about what and how and even screenshots etc. - that is quite exceptional and very nice ;-) however it could be still better if you presented what you exaclty have done. I don't think people will read the linked pages. There are a lot of comments etc. so we can't know what you exactly have now.

Answer (score 0):

An error message was given here:

> include(BbiiPost.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

You said that the Bbii was working with Yii and it broke when you tried to add comments.
The links to your var_dump files are broken, but I did try to read them ;)

It looks like the comments module is interfering with the POST path so that when the form submission comes in it is in a different path from the root which is confusing the YiiBase's autoloader.

You could try explicitly adding the path to BbiiPost.php to the autoloader's search path, or finding where the `include("BbiiPost.php")` line is and changing it to an absolute path.

Another possibility is that the forum page you are on has links to add comments but the page routing has not been taken from the route. So it might be that the POST link to the comments is actually at /forum/123/comment/add instead of just /comment/add. So when the form is submitted it is trying to the comments/add controller/action but finding that it is in /forum/view and getting confused about the paths to the include files.

I have generally found that the instructions on the Yii (v1) [v2 docs are much better] site for these modules is flaky at best. Quite often the source download link on the page points to an old buggy version of the code as the project has usually moved somewhere else. You generally need to have a pretty good PHP/Yii knowledge to debug these user-submitted modules and get them working.